# How do I replace all instances of any special characters between each occurrence of a set of delimiters in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to replace all instances of any special characters between each occurrence of a set of delimiters in a string. I believe the solution will include some combination of a regular expression *match* to retrieve the text between each set of delimiters and a regular expression *replace* to replace each offending character within the match with a space. Here’s what I have so far:

```
string input = "***XX*123456789~N3*123 E. Fake St. Apt# 456~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*902122405~REF*EI*902122405~HL*1*1*50*0~SBR*P*18*******MA~NM1*IL*1*Tom*Thompson*T***MI*123456789A~N3*456 W. False Ave.*Apt. #6B~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*90210~DMG*";
string matchPattern = "(~N3\\*)(.*?)(~N4\\*)";
string replacePattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]?";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, matchPattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    match.Value = "~N3*" + Regex.Replace(match.Value, replacePattern, " ") + "~N4*";
}

MessageBox.Show(input);
```

I would expect the message box to show the following:

```
"***XX*123456789~N3*123 E  Fake St  Apt  456~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*902122405~REF*EI*902122405~HL*1*1*50*0~SBR*P*18*******MA~NM1*IL*1*Tom*Thompson*T***MI*123456789A~N3*456 W  False Ave *Apt   6B~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*90210~DMG*"
```

Obviously this isn’t working because I can’t assign to the matched value inside the loop, but I hope you can follow my thought process. It is important that any characters which are not between the delimiters remain unchanged. Any direction or advice would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Regex.Replace` with a match evaluator where you may call the second `Regex.Replace`:

```
string input = "***XX*123456789~N3*123 E. Fake St. Apt# 456~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*902122405~REF*EI*902122405~HL*1*1*50*0~SBR*P*18*******MA~NM1*IL*1*Tom*Thompson*T***MI*123456789A~N3*456 W. False Ave.*Apt. #6B~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*90210~DMG*";
string matchPattern = @"(~N3\*)(.*?)(~N4\*)";
string replacePattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]";

string res = Regex.Replace(input, matchPattern, m =>
        string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
        m.Groups[1].Value, 
        Regex.Replace(m.Groups[2].Value, replacePattern, " "), // Here, you modify just inside the 1st regex matches
        m.Groups[3].Value));
Console.Write(res); // Just to print the demo result
// => ***XX*123456789~N3*123 E  Fake St  Apt  456~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*902122405~REF*EI*902122405~HL*1*1*50*0~SBR*P*18*******MA~NM1*IL*1*Tom*Thompson*T***MI*123456789A~N3*456 W  False Ave  Apt   6B~N4*Beverly Hills*CA*90210~DMG*
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/A2qA3u)

Actually, since `~N3*` and `~N4*` are literal strings, you may use a single capturing group in the pattern and then add those delimiters as hard-coded in the match evaluator, but it is up to you to decide what suits you best.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!